# Switch statement for multiple cases

Tags: c, switch-statement

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what is the purpose of the marked portions? ([source](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=Oocvzp8UKbQC&pg=SA14-PA4&lpg=SA14-PA4&dq=foreground%20background%20switch%20enum&source=bl&ots=Gdayd1092e&sig=QXC5UDOQVe7oQNIhLSTnx57Cy6Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixjpuX6sHXAhXLsI8KHaeMBOIQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q&f=false))

I know that we can use multiple case statement like below

```
case black:
printf ("black\n");
break;    
case blue:
case cyan:
case red:
printf("blue");
break;
```

Comment: That looks like a typo in the book, or maybe that's a really old version of non-standard C. The correct syntax is what you posted in the second part.

Answer (score 2):

They're actually regular labels that could be used as the target for a `goto`.  That is, you could write `goto cyan;` somewhere in the function and it would jump to the label `cyan:` inside the switch.

It is likely they're a thinko error — they're probably intended to be case labels `case cyan: case green: case magenta: …`.  Note that one of the classic errors in a `switch` is to introduce a label `defualt:` instead of the `default:` label.

---

Looking a bit harder at the code in the image, it is appallingly badly laid out.  After the `foreground = blue;` assignment, there is a `case white:` label which is not in the scope of a `switch` statement, so that's a syntax error.  And the `switch (background)` is followed by `{   }` all on one line, so there is no code in the `switch` and the `case black:` label is also outside of any `switch` and hence also a syntax error.

It is conceivable that there's a page fold down the middle of the lower portion of the text, in which case it's curious that the `enum colors` is spread over the fold line.  The code then makes some sort of sense, though.

If the code is all on one page and 'formatted' like that, then it is grotesque.

If that's not an isolated example of abysmal code, then you should throw the book away, now.  I mean that most sincerely — a book containing that mess isn't worth diddly-squat.  You won't know when it is teaching you anything useful and when it is teaching you complete garbage.  Don't risk it; throw it away. (And if your teacher wrote the book, change classes now.)